# Page Does Not Recognize SESSION

Tags: php, session

I have come along something i could not solve for so long. 
 i have created a script in php that unsets one single session variable, However the page stats the session Here is my code for the page :

```
    <?php
session_start();

require_once("../header.php");
    if($_SESSION['user']) {

    unset($_SESSION['user']);
        echo "you succesfully logged out.";
        header("Refresh:5; url=http://www.webmasteroutlet.com");


    } else {    
        echo "you are already NOT LOGGED IN right now.";
    }
require_once("../footer.php");
?>
```

That is the whole code on this page. and it always prints out "you are already NOT LOGGED IN right now."  `$_SESSION['user']` is assigned true in login.php page and i have `session_start();` at the very beginning of the page right after the `<?php` opening.
The session variable is recognized at all other files with php extension and that is the only single file that it is not working on. I also tried

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user'];
?>
```

and it does not print anything. It simply skips that line  and does nothing. What am i doing wrong ? 
Thank You very much for your help. 
this is the header.php code

```
<?php 
session_start();
require("config.php"); // that only contains connection to the database and it is successful.

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])==1){
                    echo "<div id=\"topnav\" class=\"topnav\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"signup\"><span>".$_SESSION['username']."</span></a>  <a href=\"http://www.webmasteroutlet.com/users/logout.php\" class=\"signup\"><span>LOGOUT</span></a></div>";
                }
            else    if ($_SESSION['admin']) {
                    echo "<div id=\"topnav\" class=\"topnav\">"."<a href=\"#\" class=\"signup\"><span>".$_SESSION['adminusername']."</span></a>  ";
                    echo "<a href=\"http://www.webmasteroutlet.com/admin/adminlogout.php\" class=\"signup\"><span>LOGOUT</span></a></div>";
                }
            else     if ( !isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
                    require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/users/login.php");
                }


require("search.php");
?>
```

Comment: It sounds like maybe `$_SESSION['user']` is not set. Try `var_dump($_SESSION['user'])` to see what the value really is.

Comment: if session is not set, when he puts on his next code, wouldn't it show up an error?

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SESSION)`

Comment: @Mike_Moto depends on what E_ error level he is using. But yeah, var_dump it

Comment: i tried that just now and it says NULL however in all the other pages it prints 1. i still dont see where the problem is when it is working properly on all the other pages.

Comment: so it's not set for this page then

Comment: Have you tried setting the value to anything other than true? Such as 'user' or something..

Comment: If it works on other pages, perhaps you have a some white-space on this one before you try to start the session. You can check that with `headers_sent`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once("../header.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

echo "User.".$_SESSION['user']." you are being logged out";
unset($_SESSION['user']);

    header("Refresh:5; url=http://www.webmasteroutlet.com");


} else {    
    echo "You are not logged or var SESSION doesnt exist";
}
require_once("../footer.php");
?>
```

If still doesnt work, try deleting the require_once lines(for debug).

Comment: justin, this page of code is a logout right? you're redirecting to this from someone clicking logout button on another page yes?

Comment: yes in the header.php it display either login or logout in html a tag and it comes from there.

Comment: can you show us what's in your header.php and wherever the link is coming from? the Session must be unsetting or something before the page loads.

Comment: i just added the header.php code where link is being directed from. and i also tried isset to and didn not change the result.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need the if is set and make sure you pass the sessions data to this page it looks like your unsetting this

Comment: i also tried that too. i am thinking something else is causing the trouble and its walue is NULL when i say echo var_dump($_SESSION['user']); what does it men when it says null?

Comment: null when you var_dump means it's not set or its equal to false

Answer (score 0):

Justin, I think you're not setting the `$_SESSION['user']`. That'd be the reason why you're getting NULL when you vardump.

One other possibility, although I'm limited to the scripts you provided, would be that you made it possible for a person to login through `$_SESSION['admin']` as well as `$_SESSION['user']`. If this is the case you'd have to change the script to:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
    echo "user succesfully logged out.";
}elseif(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
    unset($_SESSION['admin']);
    echo "admin succesfully logged out.";
}else{    
    echo "you are already NOT LOGGED IN right now.";
}
```

Comment: Please look at the header.php code, it has an if statement and if condition is working on the same variable and when i log in it displays LOGOUT, and when not logged in it displays LOGIN perfectly so i am sure the $_SESSION['user'] is set to true.

Comment: hard to help without seeing all of the files and testing but, by any chance do you have it so that the admin is logged in, and the user isn't. And at the moment when you try it, the admin cannot log off because you're only addressing the unsetting of the $_SESSION['user']

Comment: My website also has an admin panel but it works just perfectly on adminlogout page. you look at the header and can see that it is functioning just fine. Something along the way is causing it to be set to NULL. what could possibly cause that?

Comment: justin. last thing. the page that has the link to which this logout php page is being execute (the page where the user had to click logout to get to the current scripts you've shown us), you need to make sure you didn't destroy the session before having the user leave the page. Did you by any chance have the session_destroy code in there somewhere?

Comment: no i check multuple times, And when i come back to the index.php page user is still logged in. If it was destroying the session it would not be logged in any more.